# PDF de tamanho estilo cupom

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Preciso criar um PDF estilo cupom, para enviar para uma impressora não fiscal Daruma DR800.

Eu preciso saber como gerar um PDF com tamanho personalizado e o seu conteudo. Eu já faço geração de PDF com o DOMPDF no Laravel 5.5.

Exemplo de como gera um PDF qualquer:

```
public function printSimple($id)
{
    $sale = $this->sale::where('id', $id)->with('user', 'customer', 'products', 'promissory')->get()->first();
    $company = Company::find(1);
    $view = view('sale.print-simple', compact('sale', 'company'));
    $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($view)->setPaper('a4');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

Estilo esta imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você tem o código desse cupom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar o tamanho do papel da seguinte forma:

```
 ->setPaper([0, 0, 807.874, 221.102], 'landscape')
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado amigo.

Comment: Eu fiz essa configuração e funcionou, mas altura do cupom fica sempre no tamanho de uma A4, gostaria de saber se tem como deixar a altura de forma dinâmica, porque quando o produto tem somente 1 ou 2 produtos fica todo um espaço em branco sobrando em baixo.